# Does this code cause memory leaks?

Tags: c, malloc, or-operator

Someone here asked a questions about the `||` operator. He wondered why `(j=3) || (i=3)` did not assign 3 to i. That post is here: [Determining the print of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862820/determining-the-print-of-c/)

In my first answer to that question I gave this example for how this "feature" could be used:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)) || printf("Error\n");
```

Yes, I know it should be printed to stderr, but that's not the topic. If I remember it correctly, I was told that this construct could cause memory leaks. I find it hard to believe, so please explain to me.

And is there any special reason to not use this construct? Apart from the obvious "because I can" impression it gives?

Comment: Don't use it because it is the code of a dilettante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `malloc` fails, you won't realize it; instead, you'll treat the return value from `printf` (the number of characters printed) as a memory address, leading to undefined behavior.

This is worse than a memory leak.

Putting parentheses around the assignment will fix this issue, by always assigning `ptr` to the result of `malloc`:

```
(ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))) || printf("Error\n");
```

However, you'll still need to make sure to avoid using the pointer if the allocation fails, so it won't save you much code.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. So thats why he put those extra parenthesis around the left operand?

Comment: Yes; putting parentheses around the assignment will fix this issue.